# How do I pinpoint correct result in MYSQL Query when using Join and the 2 tables have field with same name?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a join and the result of the join is correct, but then I want to display a variable, but it's not in variable format like $variable, it's in the format $row['field'], however, it doesn't display the correct value because the field name is in both tables.

Sometimes it displays the left one, sometimes it displays the right one. i don't know how to force it to display the one i want.

So for example i have this query:

```
SELECT
    user_table.*, user_groups.*
FROM
    user_table
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.groupid = user_table.usergroup
WHERE
    user_table.client = "0"
AND user_table.usergroup != "1"
ORDER BY
    user_groups.name ASC
```

Not going to put in every field, because there are too many, just a few to get the idea.

user_table:

```
userid, username, usergroup, fname, sname, company
```

user_groups:

```
groupid, name, userid
```

The JOIN will have a result like the following:

```
userid  username  usergroup  fname  sname   company  groupid  name   userid1
1129    whatever  2286       first  last    abc      2286     abc    0
```

Then i begin to echo all the fields like so:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['username']." ".$row['userid']." ".$row['company']." ".$row['fname']." ".$row['sname']." ".$row['username'];
}
```

All the data will be correct except the userid. it will use the zero(0) instead of the 1129 which is the one i want.

I have tried all of the following for the userid echo:

```
$row['userid']
$row['userid0']
$row['userid1']
$row['userid[0]']
$row['userid[1]']
$row['userid'][0]
$row['userid'][1]
```

Nothing works. it either displays the wrong one from the result, or displays nothing.

Comment: What you describe isn't possible. If two fields have the same name, MySQL complains they the fieldname is not unique.

Comment: And if userid is in both tables, obviously its wrong to not be joining on it...

Comment: @developerwjk, not so, the duplicate name stuff is a client-side (php) problem, caused by `SELECT *`. There's no special requirement that tables must be joined on columns that share names. That's a good way to design schemas, but certainly not the only way.

Comment: @OllieJones, Maybe its because of `user_table.*, user_groups.*` rather than listing them out, or maybe I'm thinking MSSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP tries to map the column names into `key => value` pairs. If there is a column with a duplicate name, then you'll only get one.

Map out second `userid` columns in MySQL using the `AS` keyword (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to give the second `userid` field a different name.

```
SELECT
    user_table.*, user_groups.groupid, user_groups.name, user_groups.userid AS group_userid
FROM
    user_table
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.groupid = user_table.usergroup
WHERE
    user_table.client = "0"
AND user_table.usergroup != "1"
ORDER BY
    user_groups.name ASC
```

You can then access the two fields like this:

```
$row['userid']; // client.userid
$row['group_userid']; // user_groups.userid
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for. I need to remember that AS feature. I ran across it before, but didn't learn or memorize when it's needed.